# dplyr::rowwise, mutate, and NA error

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use `rowwise` and `mutate` with a function that can return an NA value, but am getting an error. Consider this contrived example (which obviously is not a case for rowwise, but illustrates the error):

This works:

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(k=rnorm(10)) %>% mutate(l = ifelse(k > 0, 1, NA))

           k  l
1  -1.40223573 NA
2   1.47581873  1
3   0.35938746  1
4   0.87240448  1
5  -0.61991535 NA
6  -1.88152820 NA
7   0.25837350  1
8  -0.02250385 NA
9   0.92757943  1
10  0.49023792  1
```

But this gives an error:

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(k=rnorm(10)) %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(l = ifelse(k > 0, 1, NA))

Error: incompatible types, expecting a numeric vector
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note:** I have filed [github issue #1448](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1448) regarding the error in the result of this answer.

**Update Oct 29, 2015:** It looks like this bug in `rowwise()` has been fixed.  Check the link above for the details.

---

First off, there is no reason to make this a row-wise operation.

As far as the error goes, `NA` is of logical type. You will need to use `NA_real_` in your call to `ifelse()` in this row-wise operation.  Or as Ben Bolker notes in the comments below, you can wrap `ifelse()` with `as.numeric()`.

```
data.frame(k = rnorm(10)) %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(l = ifelse(k > 0, 1, NA_real_))
# Source: local data frame [10 x 2]
# Groups: <by row>
# 
#                k     l
#            (dbl) (dbl)
# 1  -1.7105691140    NA
# 2  -0.0702667985    NA
# 3  -0.5505724960    NA
# 4  -0.7444839870    NA
# 5  -0.0005646999    NA
# 6  -0.3702584194    NA
# 7   0.2596026787     1
# 8   0.4149810662    NA  <-- error here pointed out by David A (see comments)
# 9  -0.4698540654    NA
# 10  1.0961705022     1
```

Note that you could also use integers, as in

```
mutate(l = ifelse(k > 0, 1L, NA_integer_))
```

But you can't mix logicals and reals/integers in row-wise ops it seems.

Comment: more clunkily, `as.numeric(ifelse(...))` will also work

Comment: @BenBolker Since it's rowwise, `mutate(l = if (k > 0) 1 else NA_real_ )` works too. Probably, it should *not* be rowwise, though.

Comment: Thanks, so I'm guessing there's some philosophy behind this (rowwise, probably?) having to do with not casting values when putting them into a vector?

Comment: @blindJesse `rowwise` probably binds results for rows together, expects them to have the same class and refuses to coerce the classes to match, yeah.

Comment: Did anyone notice that the results are incorrect here? row 8 should be 1, for example

Comment: The results will be correct without `rowwsie` though.

Comment: Huh. Repeatable here. Not everytime though. And obviously rowwise is not needed for this example. But I was going for the simplest case.